# Update string from different object's OnTouchAction

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding, touch, effect

I have an object class that derives from BoxView. The object has TouchEffect attached and when the OnTouchAction starts, I change the object's properties.

I would also like to change the property of a label based on the text attached to the string that label is bound to.

What I did is I created an instance of the page that contains bindable string and label, then, I tried to change the value of string by referencing it in code inside the OnTouchAction method.

I don't get errors and the Breakpoint tells me that code arrives to the line, but the label is not being updated.

I am trying to update the string from the class that is not the same where the string is.

Is there anyone who could help me out here?

```
class Element : BoxView
{
    List<long> ids = new List<long>();
    MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();

    public event EventHandler StatusChanged;

    public Element()
    {
        TouchEffect effect = new TouchEffect();
        effect.TouchAction += OnTouchEffectAction;
        Effects.Add(effect);
    }

    public Color DefaultColor { set; get; }

    public Color HighlightColor { set; get; }

    public bool IsPressed { private set; get; }

    void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Type)
        {
            case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                AddToList(args.Id);
                mainPage.LeftLabelText = "entered";
                break;

            case TouchActionType.Entered:
                if (args.IsInContact)
                {
                    AddToList(args.Id);
                    mainPage.LeftLabelText = "entered";
                }
                break;

            case TouchActionType.Moved:
                break;

            case TouchActionType.Released:
            case TouchActionType.Exited:
                RemoveFromList(args.Id);

                break;
        }
    }

    void AddToList(long id)
    {
        if (!ids.Contains(id))
        {
            ids.Add(id);
        }

        CheckList();
    }

    void RemoveFromList(long id)
    {
        if (ids.Contains(id))
        {
            ids.Remove(id);
        }

        CheckList();
    }

    void CheckList()
    {
        if (IsPressed != ids.Count > 0)
        {
            IsPressed = ids.Count > 0;
            Color = IsPressed ? HighlightColor : DefaultColor;
            mainPage.LeftLabelText = "entered";
            StatusChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

and the MainPage relevant code:

```
Element element = new Element();
                            element.HighlightColor = Color.Accent;
                            element.DefaultColor = Color.Transparent;
                            element.Color = bar.DefaultColor;
                            element.HeightRequest = sGrid.Height;    
                            element.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;

(...) // adding element view to the grid.
```

The string:

```
public string _leftLabelText = "testing";
    public string LeftLabelText
    {
        get => _leftLabelText;
        set
        {
            _leftLabelText = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LeftLabelText");
        }
    }

 #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged2;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged2?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion



<Label x:Name="leftLabel" x:FieldModifier="public" Text="{Binding LeftLabelText, Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

Comment: where is LeftLabelText bound to a UI element?

Comment: I set the binding in xaml

Comment: I've just read about MessagingCenter, I will give that a try